# swift stacked bar chart

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using the [Charts library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) in Swift to draw bar charts.

Here is my code:

```
class barChartVC: UIViewController {

    let months = ["January" , "February" , "March" , "April" , "May" , "June" , "July" , "August"]
    let unitsSold = [10.0,20.0,30.0,20.0,20.0,10.0,15.0,20.0]
    let unitsSold1 = [20.0,30.0,50.0,40.0,30.0,20.0,45.0,50.0]

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    @IBOutlet var barChartView: BarChartView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setChartBarGroupDataSet(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold, values2: unitsSold1, sortIndex: 0)
    }

    func setChartBarGroupDataSet(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double], values2: [Double],sortIndex:Int) {
        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count
        {
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: values[i], y: Double(i))
            let dataEntry1 = BarChartDataEntry(x: values2[i], y: Double(i))
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry1)
        }

        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: " ")

        var COLOR_SET = [UIColor]()
        COLOR_SET = [UIColor.red,UIColor.green]

        chartDataSet.setColors(COLOR_SET, alpha: 1.0)

        let dataSets: [BarChartDataSet] = [chartDataSet]

        let data = BarChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
        barChartView.data = data // Fatal error is here

        barChartView.descriptionText = "Bar Chart"
        barChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
        barChartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
        barChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false
        barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .easeInBounce)   
    }
}
```

I am getting a fatal error on the line that I marked in the code.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Thank you in advance to people who help me.

Comment: "Getting fatal error for the line I marked in code" And what error exactly ? What's the whole error message? Usually, it's verbose and useful to debug.

Comment: Try changing: `let data = BarChartData(dataSets: dataSets)` to `let data = BarChartData(dataSet: dataSets)`

Comment: @NoahCristino Tried your suggestion and still the same fatal error.

Comment: Try to make your data set, and data look like this example:                       
`let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")`
 `let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: months, dataSet: chartDataSet)`

Comment: @NoahCristino BarChartData(dataSet : ) accepts only single argument.

Comment: `barChartView`: Is it linked in InterfaceBuilder? My guess is that it's not. Or `data` is nil.

Comment: @Larme No , as per my understanding BarChartView comes from CHARTS Library.

Comment: @swiftuser123 No `@IBOutlet var barChartView: BarChartView!`, that's from YOUR code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run your code with no errors. I believe the problem you are facing is with the IBOutlet.

Make sure the selected class in your storyboard is BarChartView and 
that your view in storyboard is connected to the IBOutlet in your ViewController

[image]